# Cannot open .jar files?

Tags: raspbian, java

I have installed JDK 8 and JRE 8 however whenever I try to open .jar files nothing happens. E.g. in terminal I type java -jar filename.jar then it just takes me to my next terminal input.

If I open-with it from my desktop, I get the timer-cursor (as if it was loading), but then again nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Have you updated your $PATH and made it your default in .profile?

Comment: how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you have updated your PATH and made it your default in .profile.

Please see [detailed instructions from Java here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

From memory, last time I did it, I think I edited this file:

```
~/.profile
```

And specified like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0/bin:$PATH
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

When you type `java -version` at your command prompt what response do you get?

If you get a response indicating the JVM and version number, you will know Java has been installed correctly.

If you `echo $JAVA_HOME`
the response should be your path to Java install.

Assuming these two items are working and your executable still doesn't work, then you need to define your main entry point into your program.

Comment: echo $JAVA_HOME returns nothing

Comment: java -version works fine

Comment: I'm so confused

Comment: Deep breathe....... which OS you are using?   Can you provide the information returned from the command echo $JAVA_HOME?

Comment: I assume you are using OpenJDK, but would like to be sure.

Comment: Here is an excellent post from Ubuntu Exchange.   http://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java

Comment: I just performed this on a machine to confirm this works.  You likely will have the file /etc/environment on your system.  The classpath to your jvm will be i.e.:  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 if it is OpenJDK.  Let me know if this helps.